# How to have a complete colored background in a table in GTK+2?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk2, gtktreeview

The method I employed is

```
self.table.insert_column_with_attributes(-1, 'Node IP Address', IPAdd, text=0, background=3)
```

But I realized that the gaps between cells, or rather, the borders, do not apply the background color. Is there a good way to completely colorize that portion as well?

[image: Table with background color]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "cell-background" property of the text renderer instead of setting the background of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code sample

```
treeview.set_model(model)
col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Header")
cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
treeview.append_column(col)
col.pack_start(cell, 0)
col.set_attributes(cell, text=0) 
cell.set_property('background', '#color')
```

For more gtk.CellRendererText Properties : [CellRendererText](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcellrenderertext.html)